# Reading a text from a file in java with ArrayList

Tags: java, file, arraylist

I want to write a method for reading a data from a file in java using ArrayList instead of static String[] array. This is what I wrote so far:

```
public static ArrayList<String> loadText(String file) {
    ArrayList<String> ret = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String line = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                ret.add(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

And this is how i called this method in my Test class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<String> text = Files.loadText("podaci.txt");

        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

There is a problem with:

ret.add(line);

I'm getting NullPointerException, and i can't figure out why...

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: "Can you help me with this?", what's the specific issue you're having? And something I can see immediately is that your "ret" arraylist hasn't been created, and you are trying to add to it

Comment: I guess that `ret` is `null` since you haven't initialized it.

Comment: What do you mean  "ret" arraylist hasn't been created, what about this: ArrayList<String> ret = null;   ??

Comment: It should be `ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: If you assign ret to null, how can you call the add() method on null?

Comment: uuuuuuuuh, how i didn't see that, yeea, sorry for stupid question, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
ArrayList<String> ret = null;
```

sets the variable ret to null.
It should not be surprising that the the line

```
ret.add(line);
```

throws a NullPointerException.

Consider allocating an ArrayList.
Maybe even something like this:

ArrayList ret = new ArrayList();

*Edited*